# FIPS code data combination

Tags: data

I have two datasets- matching years, different sources. They are matchable by FIPS code, but my problem is 1) that the first data set, from which I am drawing my independent variable data, only has the five-digit FIPS code data, and my other data set has information disaggregated down to the eleven digit level. Any thoughts on combining these more disaggregated data?

Comment: For people not from the US: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code

Answer (score 1):

You easiest answer is to create a new field in your table with the longer value; than extract the left 5 characters and insert them into the new field. Then you can join on that field without having made any integrity changing updates to the underlying data.
Any database has a function to select a substring of a value.